# Prob. 34, Exercises 6.9, in Apostol's CALCULUS Vol. 1: For a function $f$, continuous on $(0,+\infty)$, the integral $\int_x^{xy}f(t)dt$ is . . .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Here is Prob. 34, Exercises 6.9, in the book *Calculus* Vol. 1 by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> A function $f$, continuous on the positive real axis, has the property that for all choices of $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, the integral
> $$
> \int_x^{xy} f(t) \, dt
> $$
> is independent of $x$ (and therefore depends only on $y$). If $f(2) = 2$, compute the value of the integral $A(x) = \int_1^x f(t) \, dt$ for all $x > 0$.

My Attempt:

> As $f$ is continuous on the positive real axis, so we have $A^\prime (x) = f(x)$ for all $x > 0$. In particular, we have $A^\prime (2) = f(2) = 2$.

What next? How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you differentiate$$\int_x^{xy}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\tag1$$in order to $x$, you get $yf(xy)-f(x)$. But $(1)$ is independent of $x$, and therefore this expression must be $0$. So, you always have$$f(xy)=\frac{f(x)}y.$$It follows that\begin{align}A(x)&=\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_1^xf\left(2\times\frac t2\right)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_1^x\frac{f(2)}{t/2}\,\mathrm dt\\&=4\int_1^x\frac1t\,\mathrm dt\\&=4\log(x).\end{align}